# HDFS behavior: Datanodes up but all data goes to one node (using -copyFromLocal)

Tags: hadoop, formatting, hdfs

I have a cluster configuration.

1. Master (also a slave)
2. Two slaves
3. Replication factor = 1

I copied a ~9GB file, `movies.txt` into hdfs as:

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal movies.txt /input/
```

I observed that half of the blocks were saved to Master and other half were distributed on the two slaves.

**Then** I thought of formatting the hadoop_stores using:

```
stop-all.sh
rm -rf {hadoop_store}/*
hdfs namenode -format

ssh slave1
rm -rf {hadoop_store}/*
hdfs namenode -format
exit

ssh slave2
rm -rf {hadoop_store}/*
hdfs namenode -format

start-all.sh
```

**Now**, when I tried

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal movies.txt /input/
```

Shockingly, I got all the blocks on `master` !

For reference my `hdfs_site.xml` is:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value> 
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Any explanation what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. When a file is being written to HDFS the very first replica is always located on a local node. And when replication factor is 1, then all blocks are stored only on a local node. When space on the local node is run out, then, I suppose, HDFS tries to store block on other nodes. It seems that happened the first time you copied the file before formatting HDFS.

Comment: Is there any command/utility to either enforce a fair distribution of blocks or re-balance the block distribution?

Comment: Though your question is related, according to SO rules, you should start a new topic, if this wasn't answered before. I'll be glad to answer.

Comment: Right, anyways, meanwhile I figured out a utility 'hadoop balancer'. Though it is super-slow. I will raise another question in case I could not find any better alternative.

Comment: Hadoop balancer won't help always, cause it equates number of blocks on all nodes in total, it doesn't balance block placement for one file.